# How to find exponential lambda parameters to maximise n parts of series of events likelihood?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

I have a series of events. I think there are n periods that make up this series. (I do not know the bounds of the periods). I assume that the delay between the events of each of these periods follows exponential distribution (again I do not know the lambda parameters of those distributions) . Do you know if anyone has ever developed an algorithm to solve this problem, i.e. **find those unknown parameters (number of periods, bounds of periods and lambdas)** that would maximise the likelihood?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the delays follow an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)? (i.e. a Poisson point *process*)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Yeah I'm sorry, exponential distribution, right

Comment: It looks like a generative model for events modelization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we simplify to assume that the [segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-series_segmentation) boundaries coincide with events, then we can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to maximize the likelihood.

First consider the case of a single segment. The data consists of $n+1$ distinct events, occuring at times $t_0 < \ldots < t_n$. If we assume that the waiting times $\tau_i = t_{i+1} - t_{i}$ are independent and identically ([exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)) distributed with rate parameter $\lambda$, then the likelihood is
$$
L = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda T}
$$
where
$$
T = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tau_i = t_n - t_0
$$
is the length of the segment, equal to the sum of waiting times.

To simplify the optimization, rather than maximizing the likelihood, we can minimize the cost
$$
c \equiv -\log{L} = \lambda T - n \log\left(\lambda\right)
$$

Minimizing the single-segment cost gives
$\hat{c} \equiv \min_{\lambda} c\left(\lambda\right) =
c\left(\hat{\lambda}\right)$, where for $n>0$ we have
$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{n}{T}$$
and
$$\hat{c} = n\left(1 - \log\left(\frac{n}{T}\right)\right)$$
and for $n=0$ we have $\hat{c} = \hat{\lambda} = 0$.

---

For the $K$-segment case, let $c_{i,j}$ be the cost to group events $t_i$ through $t_j$ into a single segment. (This corresponds to $n=j-i$ and $T=t_j-t_i$ in the above formulas.)

For $N+1$ events, the cost of a segmentation
$$0 = i_0 < i_1 < \ldots < i_{K-1} < i_K = N$$
is the sum of segment costs
$$\sum_{k=1}^K c_{i_{k-1}, i_k}$$

To minimize this sum-over-segments error, dynamic programming uses the following idea. Given an optimum segmentation of an event sequence into $k$ segments, removing the last segment (and its events) gives an optimal segmentation of the remaining *prefix* sequence into $k-1$ segments.

Let $C_{k,j}$ be the minimum cost to divide events $t_0$ to $t_j$ into $k$ segments. Then the prefix-segmentation argument above means that
$$
C_{k,j} = \min_{i}\left( C_{k-1,i} + c_{i,j} \right)
$$
where $i$ is the last event in the prefix sequence (which is also the first event in the $k$-th segment).

This recursion allows the optimum solution, $C_{K, N+1}$, to be computed by filling in the $C_{k,i}$ table.

The details are given in the "Dynamic programming segmentation" pseudo-code on page 4 of [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14675048320190694535). (Note that you can ignore their "segment error computation", which is based on a Gaussian linear model. For your case this will be the $c_{i,j}$ formula I gave above.)

Comment: thks for your answer I'm lookin at it